# ツアーの一番下に、スタックエクスチェンジの宣言がある

Tags: 討議

[ツアーページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)の一番下に、スタックエクスチェンジのアピールがあります。現在SEネットワークは英語のみです。このアピールはどうしましょうか？

Comment: StackExchangeの一部であることは変わらない訳ですから、現状維持で良いのでは？しいて気にするなら、リンク先(StackExchange)が英語サイトであることを明記すれば十分かと思いました。